# How to call Spring web service from RPG?

Tags: java, web-services, spring, db2, rpgle

We have developed SOA architecure for our intranet application, so our web-start java applications are connected to central app. server which is running on Spring HttpInvoker, things work pretty well. Now, we came up with need to centralize our business logic, so our need is to call these web services from DB2 RPG stored procedures. Is that possible and what could you suggest to start with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be best to ask this on the [RPG400-L](http://lists.midrange.com/listinfo/rpg400-l) list. There are many XML experts in there.

RPG can do XML on V5R4 and above. There are other tools like the [RPG-XML](http://www.rpg-xml.com/) that could help as well.